# using "&amp;" in appSettings in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I'm trying to store a website address in the appSettings section of the web.config file.  The URL has two querystring paramters at the end of the URL so I need to use the & symbol.  When I hard code the URL in the code file it works if I substitute `"&amp;"`.   In the config file these letters are red.  I've tried both "&" and `"&amp;"` in the config and they both turn red and I can't read them from the code file.   Can anyone tell me how to do this so that it works?

Thanks,

EDIT:

It looks like it's not reading anything from the appSettings.  I'm using this line to retrieve the setting.

```
String surveyLink = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SatisfactionSurveyLink"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a web.config file when I should have been using an app.config file in my test project

Answer (score 18):

Given that the web.config file is XML itself, if you want a string to *actually* be `&amp;` you need to effectively encode it twice. Try:

```
&amp;amp;
```

When the XML is decoded, this will convert to `&amp;` in the string, which will then be decoded again to `&` appropriately, by the sounds of it. Having said that, it's not *really* clear why you need `&amp;` in the URL rather than `&` if you're trying to give *two separate query parameters*.

Comment: we can use single &amp; and &amp;amp; both will print the same value '&'

Comment: @SantoshK: No, `&amp;amp;` has a different meaning - it means the content `&amp;`. Now if you're using that *as HTML* then sure, it'll display as `&`. But the value of the decoded string will be `&amp;`.